# How to call .cs file from a .aspx.cs in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to store this method with labels in class file?
 Example:

aspx.cs

```
   private void addSalat()
    {


                    decimal sum= Convert.ToDecimal(Label6.Text);
                    decimal sum2= Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text);
                    decimal sum3= Convert.ToDecimal(Label54.Text);
                    decimal sum4= Convert.ToDecimal(Label66.Text);
                    decimal sum5= Convert.ToDecimal(Label78.Text);
                    decimal sum6= Convert.ToDecimal(Label90.Text);
                    decimal sum7= Convert.ToDecimal(Label102.Text);
                    decimal sum8= Convert.ToDecimal(Label114.Text);
                    decimal sum9= Convert.ToDecimal(Label126.Text);

                    decimal sum= sum+ sum2+
                        sum3+ sum4+ sum5+ sum6+ sum7+ sum8
                        + sum9;

                    Label42.Text = sum.ToString();
                }
```

//do calculations here and call this method in aspx.cs file, i dont't know how to put here labels if is possible:

```
 public class Class1
{
    public void Sum()
    {

                    decimal sum= Convert.ToDecimal(Label6.Text);
                    decimal sum2= Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text);
                    decimal sum3= Convert.ToDecimal(Label54.Text);
                    decimal sum4= Convert.ToDecimal(Label66.Text);
                    decimal sum5= Convert.ToDecimal(Label78.Text);
                    decimal sum6= Convert.ToDecimal(Label90.Text);
                    decimal sum7= Convert.ToDecimal(Label102.Text);
                    decimal sum8= Convert.ToDecimal(Label114.Text);
                    decimal sum9= Convert.ToDecimal(Label126.Text);

                    decimal sum= sum+ sum2+
                        sum3+ sum4+ sum5+ sum6+ sum7+ sum8
                        + sum9;

                    Label42.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its possible, but you would have to calculate based on parameters instead of labels.

Comment: Are you asking if you can move this code from a code-behind to just a plain code file somewhere else in your project and still use the label objects?  If that is the case the answer is no (or at least not as is) because those objects are no longer in scope and don't exist and can't be referenced.

Comment: @Icemanind could you write small example,,you mean to store label values in variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
private decimal Sum(decimal firstValue, params decimal[] moreValues)
{
    decimal val = firstValue;

    return val + moreValues.Sum(); // Note this is not recursion. It is calling the LINQ Sum() function.
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Sum(5.2); // returns 5.2
Sum(6, 10); // returns 16
Sum(1,2,3); // returns 6
```

Or something like this:

```
decimal sum = Sum(Convert.ToDecimal(Label6.Text), 
                  Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text), 
                  Convert.ToDecimal(Label54.Text)
                  // and so forth
                  );
```

Comment: Why do you need two parameters?  Wouldn't one `params` parameter do the same thing?

Comment: @DStanley - Yes, but having two, like I have it, guarantees at least one value is passed.

Answer (score 0):

I would just leave it in the code-behind of the page. Since you're basically just adding values there's not a lot to gain by splitting it into a different class.  If you were doing more complex calculations that needed unit testing, etc. *then* I would consider splitting it out.

You could also make the code a little cleaner by using Linq to sum the values:

```
decimal sum = new [] {Label6, Label17, Label54, Label66, Label78, Label90, Label102, Label114, Label126}
              .Sum(lbl => Convert.ToDecimal(lbl.Text));
```

Comment: @buba Actually I took that out because, in the end, you're summing numbers which is one line of code.  Just keep it in the code-behind.

Comment: So?  you can keep it as a separate method in the code-behind, but in order to split it out effectively you're going to have to either expose the controls of your form or have a method that takes 9 values and add them up (which is one line of code).